# How do i monitor Internet traffic?

Tags: vb.net, winapi, bandwidth

How do i monitor internet only traffic without LAN traffic(such as file transfer between LAN) using vb

Comment: I think I saw that on CSI -- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [pcap.net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/), just make sure you listen on the right interface (assuming your internet is through PPP it would be on a separate interface). Secondly you may simply filter out all traffic between internal IPs.